# Cross-Compiling JRE/JDK

Tags: java, unix, cross-platform, debian

Have somebody experiences with cross-compiling the sun-java5 source package (debian) from i386/i586 to the hppa architecture?

Or know a source for java for PA-RISC? I've found only the Package for HP-UX.

Kaffe/gcj are not able to run my third-party java application

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how strong your stomach is (I apologize in advance in the *likely* case this doesn't work out of the box and you spend months of your life on it :-)

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/zero/

"Zero is a port of OpenJDK that uses no assembler and therefore can trivially be built on any system. The goal of this project is be to be able to build a TCK-compliant OpenJDK of reasonable performance on any platform with no additional porting work.

The interpreter part of Zero is known to work on PowerPC (32- and 64-bit), x86-64, IA-64, ARM and zSeries. Zero is currently Linux- and GCC-specific, but supporting other operating systems and compilers is one area in which contributions are particularly welcome."

Apparently it now passes the TCK